# Symfony 3.3 - my custom font is not loading

Tags: html, css, symfony, fonts, symfony-3.3

I have placed a custom font `myfont.otf` in `src/AppBundle/Resources/public/css/fonts`. Then, I put

```
@font-face {
    font-family: LogoFont;
    src: url(fonts/myfont.otf)
}

.logo{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: LogoFont, sans-serif;
}
```

inside `src/AppBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css` file.

But when I visit the page with the `<div class='logo'>Hello</div>` the font is not applied and the developer console throws 404 resource not found. What am I doing wrong? I am using assetic for assets management and the `main.css` file is properly included.

Comment: It may be to do with the paths. You should be using 'relative' paths. Try doing `src:url('./fonts/myfont.otf')`. Can you see the path that is being used to give you a `404`?

Comment: 404 error says that it fails to load `Resources/public/css/fonts/myfont.otf`, setting the location your way gives the same error. @zik

Comment: Have you tried what I mentioned above ?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same error.

Comment: I have just noticed that assetic doesnt make /fonts directory when i call assetic:dump command.